# Replace text in a file?

Tags: vb.net

I am successfully replacing a text in a file.

```
Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt").Replace("foo", "bar")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\test.txt", fileReader, False)
```

But how can I replace if I don't know the middle of the text ? For example

example_my("browser.taskbar.lastgroupid", "E7CF176E110C211B");

How to replace the **E7CF176E110C211B** ?

Comment: don't know the middle of what?

Comment: I meant how to replace the middle part only ? Lets say I dont know the  E7CF176E110C211B number. How can I change it ?

Comment: You're going to have to explain exactly what you have and what you're trying to do because we can't see your screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use RegEx. You can specify the first and last parts and then use `\d+` or better `[0-9A-F]+` to match any hex number. So given that the part that you don't know is a hexadecimal number, you can use the following code:

```
Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
fileReader = System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx.Replace(fileReader, "[0-9A-F]+", "bar")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\test.txt", fileReader, False)
```

This will replace all hexadecimal numbers in the file with the word "bar".

Note that for a text file this kind of global Replace can have undesirable results. For example the above regex will replace letters A to F even within normal text. So you'll probably want to put some kind of limitations such as min. number of digits to make sure it replaces only valid hex numbers. For example you may want to use `[0-9A-F]{4,}` which will replace only 4 or more consecutive hex digits. But even that is not 100% safe; e.g. it will replace DEAD, FACE, FADE, FACED etc. with the word "bar". To figure out exactly what is 100% safe for your file, you'll need to examine its contents carefully.

### Edit

Reading you comments, you can use the following code instead:

```
Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
fileReader = System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx.Replace(fileReader , "lastgroupid"", ""(.+)""\)", "lastgroupid"", ""ANYTHING_YOU_WANT""\)")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\test.txt", fileReader, False)
```

This will replace all occurrances of hex numbers between  **lastgroupid", "** AND **")** with the string **ANYTHING_YOU_WANT**.

Comment: Is it possible to, change the middle of specified strings, like change values between lastgroupid", " AND "); so that it replaces the text between these ?

Comment: Of course. Use `lastgroupid", ".+"\)` instead of `[0-9A-F]+` in the above code.

Comment: @user198989: Oops my mistake. I was writing it in C# format. Corrected.